# Django, JSON serialize queryset and list of models has different behavior

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a Django model with a function (on the Python class) that modifies some of its fields.

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    a_number = models.FloatField()
    some_text = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def MyFunction(self):
        self.a_number = 123.123
```

I can do this, and it works

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json.dumps(list(MyModel.objects.filter(...).values()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Now I'd like to call the function `MyModel.MyFunction` on all the models before JSON encoding them. I've tried this, but obviously it returns the fields as they are in the database, not modified by MyFunction:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(...)

for mymodel in mymodels:
    mymodel.MyFunction()
    # or mymodel.myfield = somethingelse

json.dumps(list(mymodels.values()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

So I've tried this

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(...)

_mymodels = []

for mymodel in mymodels:
    mymodel.MyFunction()
    # or mymodel.myfield = somethingelse
    _mymodels.append(mymodel)

json.dumps(_mymodels, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

but `TypeError: Object of type MyModel is not JSON serializable`.

I've read on other answers that you'd have to either install django rest framework or implement a to_json function on `MyModel`.

However, I'd like not to clutter my application to achieve a behavior that is already available. How can I tell django to behave the same way on an array of models that it behaves on a queryset of the same model?

Comment: What are the types of the members of `MyModel`?

Comment: ForeignKeys (that I could drop), DateTimeFields, CharFields, and FloatFields. Instances of MyModel have a lot of Django extra functions and clutter. Updating my question.

Comment: Updated, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.forms.models.model_to_dict` did the trick

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(...)

_mymodels = []

for mymodel in mymodels:
    mymodel.MyFunction()
    # or mymodel.myfield = somethingelse
    _mymodels.append(model_to_dict(mymodel))

json.dumps(_mymodels, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to try using `json.dumps(MyModel.objects.filter(...).values(), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`, as this will *mostly* do the same thing as `model_to_dict`, but without the overhead of creating model instances (from something like a dict) and then converting them back to dicts.

You may need to write a custom `DjangoJSONEncoder` subclass if you use any custom field types, to instruct `json.dumps()` how to encode those.

Comment: Where do you call 'MyModel.MyFunction'?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that in the original post. You _could_ do all sorts of things to call a specific function.

Comment: Yes, but the modified fields values would not persist when you call .values(), forcing you to use an array of dicts.